# How to extract required data from .prn (pcl6) file by using java..?

Tags: java

```
// extract data from .prn
```

How can i extract data from a printer generated dumb .prn file (pcl6) by 
 using java or any other language. Is there any java Api for this ,like 
 Api for pdf file read (iText). I have googled alot but not found
 anything usefull yet.
                Thanks to all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A .prn file will contain codes for whatever specific printer it was
generated for, If you know these Codes you can extract them, the rest would be plain text which can then be saved to normal .txt file.

A Workarround would be to convert it to pdf and get content and how it but i dont think this is simple programmatically. therefor you can use a PDF printer driver such as [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/) or [GhostPCL](http://www.ghostscript.com/GhostPCL.html)

Comment: thanks for replying.....I had searched alot but nowhere found the way to extract data directly from prn file...but yes there is a way to extract data from pdf...